# Can the product of non-units be an irreducible element in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let me list some definitions to avoid confusion. A ring will always be assumed to be associative.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1_R \neq 0_R$.

- $u \in R$ is called a **unit** if there exists $v \in R$ such that $uv = 1_R$.
- $a \in R$ is called an **associate** of $b \in R$ if there exists a unit $u \in R$ such that $a=bu$.
- $a \in R$ is called a **divisor** of $b \in R$ if there exists $c \in R$ such that $b=ac$.
- Nonzero element $a \in R$ is called **irreducible** if it is not a unit and its only divisors are units and its associates.

My question is the following.

> Let $a$ be an element in $R$ which is not a unit. Consider the following two conditions on $a$.
>
> 1. $a$ is irreducible.
> 2. Whenever $a=bc$ for some $b, c \in R$, either $b$ or $c$ is a unit.
>
> Are these conditions equivalent?

The answer is true when $R$ is an integral domain. Let me write down a proof for convenience.

(1=>2) Suppose $a=bc$. If $b$ is not a unit, then there exists a unit $u \in R$ such that $a=bu$. Now we have $bc=a=bu$. Since $R$ is an integral domain and $b$ is nonzero, we obtain $c=u$ and $c$ is a unit.

(2=>1)
Let $b \in R$ be a divisor of $a$. Then $a=bc$ for some $c \in R$. If $b$ is not a unit, then $c$ is a unit. Since $cv=1_R$ for some $v \in R$, we have $b=bcv=av$. Now $b$ is an associate of $a$ because $v$ is a unit.

The assumption that $R$ is an integral domain is used only in the direction (1=>2). I tried to prove it without such assumption but failed. Is it still true or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are counterexamples. For example, in $R=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ you have $2=4\cdot 2$ and both $4=-2$ and $2$ are associates of $2$. On the other hand, $2$ is irreducible as its divisors are $1, -1=5$ (units) and $2,4$ (associates).